# Handling three forms on the same page with one having multiple instances - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on an Invoice that has three forms of which one has multiple instances. The first two forms each has one instance and the last one can accommodate as many as the user wants. meaning the user will be adding instances of the last form using JavaScript. With the below code I am getting an error that is saying that the fields of the first two forms are missing data cause whenever the user add extra fields to the last form Django thinks I am also adding extra forms to the other two forms. Please help

This is an example of the POST data with two extra fields for the last form:

```
form-TOTAL_FORMS    '2'
form-INITIAL_FORMS  '0'
form-MIN_NUM_FORMS  '0'
form-MAX_NUM_FORMS  '1000'
form-0-number   '215'
form-0-customer '4'
form-0-sales_person '1'
form-0-product  '2'
form-0-quantity '20'
form-0-price    '20'
form-1-product  '2'
form-1-quantity '40'
form-1-price    '50'
```

This is my view.py

```
def createInvoice(request):
    invoiceFormSet = formset_factory(InvoiceForm)
    retailPriceFormSet = formset_factory(RetailPriceForm, extra=2)
    saleItemFormSet = formset_factory(SaleItemForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        invoiceform = invoiceFormSet(request.POST or None)
        retailPriceform = retailPriceFormSet(request.POST or None)
        saleItemform = saleItemFormSet(request.POST or None)

        if invoiceform.is_valid() and saleItemform.is_valid():
            for si in saleItemform:
                saleItem = si.save()
                saleItem_id = get_object_or_404(SaleItem, id=saleItem.id)
            for i in invoiceform:
                inv = i.save(commit=False)
                inv.sale_item = saleItem_id
                inv.save()
            for rp in retailPriceform:
                retailPrice = rp.save(commit=False)
                retailPrice.sale_item = saleItem_id
                retailPrice.save()
            return HttpResponse(retailPriceform.cleaned_data)

    context = {'invoiceFormSet':invoiceFormSet,'retailPriceFormSet':retailPriceFormSet, 'saleItemFormSet':saleItemFormSet}
    return render(request, 'createInvoice.html',context)
```

This is my template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Create Invoice {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{saleItemFormSet.as_p}}
    {{invoiceFormSet.as_p}}
    {{ retailPriceFormSet.management_form }}
    {% for form in retailPriceFormSet %}
    <div>{{form.as_p}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-normal btn-main">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a prefix to use multiple formset in a single view.
Example:

if get:,

```
article_formset = invoiceFormSet(prefix='articles')
book_formset = retailPriceFormSet(prefix='books')
```

if post:

```
article_formset = invoiceFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='articles')
book_formset = retailPriceFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='books')
```

reference: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view)

Comment: you're welcome. I think you can mark this answer as accepted.